# What do I need my (ePub) toc.ncx to have?

Tags: epub, epubcheck, ncx

I am trying to figure out an appropriate toc.ncx that EpubCheck will recognize as correct.

Right now I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ncx version="2005-1" xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/">
    <head>
        <meta content="urn:uuid:e9f75adf-f0a2-4a30-b113-b146871f16e5" name="dtb:uid"/>
        <meta content="0" name="dtb:totalPageCount"/>
        <meta content="0" name="dtb:maxPageNumber"/>
        <meta content="2" name="dtb:depth"/>
    </head>
    <docTitle>
        <text>Doxology</text>
    </docTitle>
    <docAuthor>
        <text>C.J.S. Hayward</text>
    </docAuthor>
    <navMap>
        <navPoint class="h1" id="letters.xhtml" playOrder="1"><navLabel><text>The Angelic Letters</text></navLabel><content src="letters.xhtml" /></navPoint>
<navPoint class="h1" id="spectacles.xhtml" playOrder="2"><navLabel><text>The Spectacles</text></navLabel><content src="spectacles.xhtml" /></navPoint>
<navPoint class="h1" id="doxology.xhtml" playOrder="3"><navLabel><text>Doxology</text></navLabel><content src="doxology.xhtml" /></navPoint>

    </navMap>
</ncx>
```

What should I be doing differently in this file? The error I'm getting is:

> Fatal Error while parsing file 'The prefix "ns" for element "ns:ncx" is not bound.'.

Comment: FUN FACT: toc.ncx is no longer a mandatory file in epub3 (it was only required in epub 2).  In epub3 it is no longer necessary to have a toc.ncx file (and for future versions it will be deprecated). Instead you include a HTML navigation document (which you mark by using the NAV element in that file). I've never tried deleting this file when I generate it, but I'm guessing that doing so would eliminate the error.

Comment: @idiotprogrammer I would still recommend a ncx file for compatibility with the majority of reading systems.